# What does score (for badges) mean?

Tags: support

Enlightened Badge - First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more

Here score 10 means 10 up votes or 10 points?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Score always means the number of *upvotes minus downvotes* on a post. It is the number shown next to a post, between the voting buttons.

E.g. a post with 12 upvotes and 2 downvotes has a *score* of 10.