# What is the meaning of 'Score' on the Stack Overflow Tags statistics page?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score, top-users

Where can I find information about the Stack Overflow tag statistics page, like what 'Score' means for Top Users?

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/topusers) to a sample page.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @CodyGray - i've attached a link to the page

Comment: Hover the mouse over the values.

Comment: @CodeCaster - what does `Total Score of` means?

Comment: If you take a look at "All Time - 19.5k - 2k - Johannes Schaub - litb" and hover on `19.5k`, you'll see that given user has a "All-time total score of 19.5k in the C++ tag".

Comment: @CodeCaster - sorry for not fully understanding you - what does `score` mean? how a person receive it? i am familiar with `reputation`, but what is a `score point`?

Comment: My guess is they're equal.

Comment: [What does score (for badges) mean?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251760)

Comment: @CodeCaster - taking "All Time - 19.5k - 2k - Johannes Schaub - litb" example - he has 249K reputation points... so doesn't seem the same

Comment: He may have answered more than just C++ questions.

Comment: [How to read top users page of a tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85119)

Comment: @CodyGray - thanks Cody Gray for the answer. next time i'll search in that Meta web site..

Comment: [How are tag scores calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The explanation of `Score` is found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated) [which can't be used as a canonical dupe since it's on Meta SE].

**tl;dr:**

> The sum of all values of (upvotes - downvotes) for answers that are not Community Wiki

So it's based on number of votes, not on the reputation received.