# How are tag scores calculated?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

So I'm a member for 3 months now and keen on my bronze JavaScript badge. ;-) I have this

[image]

score visible on my profile, but when I count the number of upvotes on JavaScript tagged answers I get 108. Where does the discrepancy come from?

Lately, I got 5 upvotes after being over the 200 rep limit. Are those upvotes not counted into the total tag count?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Mouse over the 96 and the tooltip tells you:

[image: tag scores for javascript]

You posted 102 answers (that are not Community Wiki) with a total net score of 96. The net score is the total number of upvotes on those answers, minus the total number of downvotes on the same (note that accepts are neither upvotes nor downvotes and don't count towards the score).

The score is recalculated once a day, around 03:00 UTC, so the two answers you posted today in that tag do not yet count, nor do up- or down votes on older answers that have been given after that time.

Comment: Ah, the good old mouseover. I'm learning something new here every day. :) thanks

Comment: So that it is explicit, can you confirm that upvoted questions do not count toward your tag score?

Comment: @StevenPenny: Yes, only *answers* count towards the tag score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I am not sure if its worth a new question, so decided to ask in comment. I've checked today my 2 main badges (`ruby`, `ruby-on-rails`) score, and it was not recalculated since yesterday. Do you know if it is still to be recalculated?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko tag scores are still being calculated, but sometimes the script fails. This can even happen a few days in a row, unfortunately.

Comment: But I mean are those earned points that were supposed to be there in score - are they going to appear later or they are gone and script will just calculate only new ones?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko they'll be there, they are not gone.

Comment: For quite some days and new database answers upvoted my Activity Next tag badge has shown bronze Database with 79/100 answers & 129/20 questions. I just went to my Tags tab and it shows 87 Database X 138. Why hasn't my Next tag badge into been updated? I noticed such a lag prior to its last update, but I don't know what ended it.

Comment: @philipxy: database overload. The script that runs every night is [known to fail from time to time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253587/can-i-haz-stinkin-silver-tag-badge-plz).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you know if deleted answers count towards the tag score?

Comment: @NathanOliver: deleted answers do not count.

Comment: Do bounty's count towards tag score? Should they?

Comment: @DaImTo: no and no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it would be useful to directly add a line about bounties definitively not counting toward tag scores since your post is likely the best resource for tag scores on Meta :).

Comment: @theforestecologist bounties are *reputation*; I don't think it is useful to mention each and every reputation event as not counting towards the tag score.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tag score = # of upvotes on answers - # of downvotes on answers
```

Note, only votes on **answers** count. Votes on **questions** *don't*.