# How do categories' bronze badge score work?

Tags: support, tag-badges

I'm not understanding how tag badges work. As I'm specializing in JavaScript, I'm trying to focus in answering JavaScript answers in order to improve my score, reputation and knowledge in it.

My objective is reach gold in JavaScript. So the first thing I've done is going in my profile and set JavaScript the "next tag badge" I'm tracking at the moment. On the beginning, I had 12/100 score and 19/20 answers. Then I started answering questions. I use to check it every couple of days.

The problem is that the badge scores stayed the same even after many answers.

I tried to re-select the badge and the score had a slight change to 13/100.
That can't be right, because only in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554138/for-loop-condition-issues/33555012#33555012) one, I earned 25 points. And I have many others. So how do I increase the tag badge score? Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Score for tag badges means the score of the post not the reputation you got for it. Accepted answers don't change it. The post you linked has a score of 1.

Comment: Question/answer score are different from reputation score.

Comment: For those that downvoted. Please explain why my question was bad. I searched help and couldn't find or understand the difference between reputation and tag badge score.

Comment: Note: I didn't downvote, but there is a meta question called "how are tag scores calculated", here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated. Took me... 30 seconds to find (I researched "tag score"). So there is a good chance someone decided it wasn't researched enough

Comment: I understand. I recognize I didn't think in searching meta like that. I'll try to do a better search next time.

Comment: In this instance I was sure it had been discussed on meta so I searched there. Normally I would suggest a google search with "site:meta.stackoverflow.com" instead :). I prefer Google's search to Stack's

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tag score is different from reputation.

To compute your score in a tag, you look at your *answers* to questions with that tag, and add the answer scores (*i.e.*, net votes) together.

So, for example, an accepted answer with a score of 1 gives you +25 reputation (+10 for the upvote, +15 for the accept), but only +1 in that tag.

Comment: Ok... now I understood. Even with your answer, I doubted the score was only 13. I checked every answer in javascript tag I gave, and as you might imagine the score correctly summed 13. I'll try harder. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Badge scores represent the *net number of votes* in answers to questions bearing that tag. Note that this is different from the earned reputation points.

So, for example, if you get 8 upvotes and 3 downvotes, that gives you +44 reputation points. But, for the purposes of tag badge scoring, that will only give you 5 of the 100 total score needed to earn a bronze badge.