# The process of acquiring tag badges

Tags: support, tags

Hey guys I was just wondering what the required criteria is for acquiring a tag badge.

For example the bronze C tag badge says that I need 100 total score earned from at least 20 (...) answers.

I have fulfilled the 20 answers requirement but it shows that I have only 30/100 reputation. My answers have been upvoted so many times I have over 1000 reputation only on C and C++ tags how is it that I have only 30/100 reputation?

Maybe the 100 total score is something else than 100 reputation?

Please advise

Comment: It needs 100 *score* (eg. upvotes), not 100 reputation.

Comment: Very related: [How are tag scores calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated)