# Does up votes received for my questions count towards tag's score?

Tags: support

I wanted to ask if up votes received for my questions are counted towards tag's score?
For example i asked a question with `haskell` tag and got 5 up votes, will it change my `haskell` score, or only answer up votes are counted

Thanks

Comment: Only answers count toward tag score.  More reading on [How are tag scores calculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated)

Comment: I don't think the question pointed to as a duplicate is a good duplicate target, as it doesn't ask about points on questions. One needs to read a lot and it is not as explicit as it should be. This question here is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly related, but for tag score, quoting the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page,

> You must have a total score of X in at least Y non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

So, it looks like only the answers are counted for tag score.

EDIT: [It's confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated#comment262639_280819).