# What is "score" in relation to badge?

Tags: support

Sorry but this is not made clear anywhere that I can find.  I would assume "*score"* is rep but as my rep is now over 4k and my "*score*" for php badge is presently 95 they don't seem to be the same thing.

What exactly is "*score*"and where is this documented?

**EDIT:**

@Everyone - is this officially documented anywhere aside from the linked duplicate question? My question specifically asks for a reference to site documentation which the linked answer does not provide.

Comment: *The net score is the total number of upvotes on those answers, minus the total number of downvotes on the same.* [src](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280819/559745)

Comment: Hmm, odd that you can't find anything.  Pasting the title of your question into a google query has two top hits that explain everything.  Did you *really* search?  Gets to be rather pointless to have a Q+A site when nobody uses it and every Q is repeated over and over again.

Comment: @HansPassant - yes I did search, using the Stackoverflow search bar.  I also searched google for "Stackoverflow points".  Guess I should have thought about the title to my question and used a third party search tool... wait.. no.  Our own search function should be able to return some relevant results which it doesn't.   Try searching "what are points"  "what are badge points", etc.  Something like this shouldn't be hard to find.  Maybe including a tooltip when you hover over "points" in your profile and/or having a word or two in the Q&A might help keep down the noise.

Comment: @Everyone - is this officially documented anywhere aside from the linked duplicate question?  My question specifically asks for a reference to site documentation which the linked answer does not provide.

Comment: @billynoah Is there any "official documentation" that says score and rep are the same thing? To the best of my knowledge, they are always used to describe completely separate things. (For example, score is used to describe the cumulative votes on Questions when searching.)

Comment: @Laurel - I wasn't able to find anything anywhere about "score" except on that meta question that is referred to above.  Can you please provide a link?

Comment: @billynoah The search functions are documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: @Laurel - I wasn't asking for search functions - are you trolling or did you misunderstand?  I'm asking for something somewhere documenting what "score" means.

Comment: Also, please note the search page you linked is for searching Q & A, I'm looking for SO or SE *documentation* - something official.  If you search the help pages nothing seems to come up: http://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=score