# Are tag badge scores points capped alongside reputation cap?

Tags: support, tag-badges, daily-reputation-limit

Some time ago, I hit the daily repcap (which means I got 20 upvotes in a day), and I answered a couple of questions after that.

I think I noticed that the score for the tag I was answering in didn't change. Is there a cap on the tag score when you reach the daily reputation cap?

Comment: meaning, do votes after rep cap count toward your tag score? (related, but don't think it's a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated)

Comment: @KevinB: exactly. So I was mistaken, the tag score doesn't have a cap, it's just a delay.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Post *score* is not capped, only *reputation* is capped.

Tag badges are based on score, not reputation, so they are not subject to capping.

Note that per-tag scores in your profile are only re-calculated once per day. There is an exception for the *Next tag badge* feature in your profile, but take into account that that score too is cached and only calculated once every so often, it is not updating in real time.

Comment: damn, repcap was one of the reasons I stopped answering questions on a given day. What can you believe in those days ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if you stop answering questions on a given day because of rep cap then you're doing it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Lankymart: it's his choice in which way he wants to participate in the gamification. I think he made a good choice. Rep cap may be a good indicator on when to cool down from SO.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that's exactly what I meant. I already spend too much time on SO. for me rep cap is a clear _stop it_ message. If I don't answer, someone else probably will.