# Badge/Tag scores for several tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I have found out [how-are-tag-scores-calculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated), but I have found nothing about several tags. So as a rule the question has several tags, will score increased for all of them, or only for the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It updates for all the tags set in the question.

You can verify by going to your own profile page and see the top tags with score and *post* count.  Example if you go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=tags page, you will notice the score of your answer in all the tags set for the question you answered.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The designation  _x2_ was a bit confusing..